# How to remove duplicate values in PHP loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Word Press with Advanced Custom Fields and have a loop to add a field (location) to an Options tag.

There are several posts with the same location, so if I loop normally I get results such as Toronto, Ottawa, Toronto, Montreal, Toronto, Toronto, Montreal, etc. I want it so it only has "Toronto, Ottawa, Montreal".

I tried to add the values to an array, then use `array_unique()`, but I do not know how to separate the values in the array.

My code -

```
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'location_info' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $locations[] = get_sub_field( 'location' ); ?>
        <option><?php echo implode('', array_unique($locations)); ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

But this prints

```
<option>TorontoOttawaMontreal</option>
<option>TorontoOttawaMontreal</option>
<option>TorontoOttawaMontreal</option>
```

I need it to print

```
<option>Toronto</option>
<option>Ottawa</option>
<option>Montreal</option>
```

Comment: Don't your `<option>` tags need a `value` attribute, e.g. `<option value="Montreal">Montreal</option>`?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not gather all elements first, remove the duplicates, and print the remaining list?

Answer (score 1):

Added htmlentities and strip tags for security because it seems like this data must be coming from users.

```
<? foreach( array_unique( $locations ) as $location ) { ?>
    <option value="<?= htmlentities( $location ) ?>"><?= strip_tags( $location ) ?></option>;
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check if value exists in array. Try below code snippet.

```
<select name="field_name">
<?php
$locations = [];
while( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    while ( have_rows( 'location_info' ) ) :
        the_row(); 
        $loc = get_sub_field( 'location' );
        if( in_array( $loc, $locations ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        $locations[] = $loc;
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $loc ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $loc ); ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php unset( $locations ) ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This is wrong, `$locations` is not defined when you do an if check, and you just echo the `$location` which is an array, which will bring errors.

Comment: where is the select tag ?

Comment: @VijayHardaha `$locations` is an array but `$location`(singular) is not. I've changed the name to $loc to make it less confusing.

Comment: Ok, This looks ok, I was assuming that `get_sub_field( 'location' )` returns an array, but I think, it returns a string then via the loop we create an array as you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'location_info' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $locations[] = get_sub_field( 'location' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile;?>

<?php $locations_options = array_unique($locations); ?>
<select>
    <?php foreach( $locations_options as $location ): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $location; ?>"><?php echo $location; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```